# Inspect Cookies on Mobile Browsers?

Tags: android, cookies, mobile, network-programming, web-developer-toolbar

Does anyone here know of a way to inspect network request information made from a mobile browser using only the phone? Like how you can view network requests through the devtools on Google Chrome but is there a way to do it on the phone? I've seen in other StackOverflow posts that you can connect the phone to a desktop and view your network requests on the desktop but I was wondering if there was a way to do it with just the phone. I've been looking for solutions and some stuff that came up:

Web debugging proxies: Requires a desktop to monitor the network requests and also requires the phone and desktop to be connected to the same wifi connection.

Eruda (https://github.com/liriliri/eruda): This was promising since it provides a devtools console which you can view directly on mobile. However, it didn't record any of the network requests I wanted to inspect for some reason...(The cookie values I am trying to view are cookies generated from Google authentication/login)

Does anyone know of other ways to retrieve/view network information specifically cookie values of network requests made from mobile browsers preferably not requiring a separate desktop to view the requests? Any help would be appreciated thank you!!!

Also, is it possible to create an app in which you can view the network requests of all users of the app made through the app? Sorry I do not know much about app development.

Comment: It seems you may be exactly looking for [Chrome Remote Debugging tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/). I don't believe this type of debugging would be viable on the device only.

Comment: Yeah but that requires you to connect the phone to a desktop. I was wondering if it was possible to view it without a desktop...

Comment: Nah, I understand. I don't think that would be viable, but this seems to have everything the desktop version does - might be the best option. If you made your own browser app, you may be able to find a way to make all of those tools fit on a secondary app page, but I imagine just the design of it would be quite challenging.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I was thinking of inspecting the source code for Eruda to see how they obtained network information but it seems like a lot of work. Do you happen to know anything about how it works?

Comment: I do not, unfortunately. I haven't had to do anything like that almost ever - and all I have used is remote debugging. As straight forward and familiar as it is, it really does seem like the best option to me, even more so than brewing your own solution.